# How to build an sd card image, without an sd card?

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, mount, sd-card

We have a scripted process that builds up an embedded install of `Debian Jesse` on an sd card. The relevant parts of the script look like this:

```
export DISK=/dev/sdb
umount ${DISK}1   # make sure no partitions mounted at the moment
umount ${DISK}2   # ditto
dd if=/dev/zero of=${DISK} bs=1M count=16   # zero partition table zone, overkill
sfdisk --in-order --Linux --unit M ${DISK} <<-__EOF__    # make partitions
    1,48,0xE,*
    ,,,-
__EOF__

mkfs.vfat -F 16 ${DISK}1 -n boot    # install file systems
mkfs.ext4 ${DISK}2 -L rootfs
```

After that, the auto mounter seems to kick in and get the sd card remounted, so we can do things like:

```
cp -v ${DIR}/u-boot/spl/u-boot-spl.bin /media/$username/boot/BOOT.BIN
cp -v ${DIR}/u-boot/u-boot.img /media/$username/boot/
cp -v ${DIR}/u-boot/uEnv.txt /media/$username/boot/
rsync -axHAX --progress ${DIR}/jessieRoot/ /media/$username/rootfs/
```

After one of us does that, then we can use `dd` to copy the contents of the card and share it with each other, making more sd cards using `dd`.

THE PROBLEM with this is twofold: 1) It's very Ubuntu/machine specific right now (assumes card is at `sdb`, etc 2) It needs an actual card, so doesn't lend itself to a build machine.

Is there a way to do the above without a card?

I tried using `dd` to just make an 8G file and then ran `sfdisk` on that (everything's a file, right?) and that part worked. But it's not clear how I'd run the `mkfs` parts to work, they seem to want to work on block device files, not sub regions of a single file that has a partition table embedded in it. And then I have the problem of mounting it. I assume I use some incantation of `mount -o loop`, but again, not sure how to do that on the sub region of the virtual image file, I've always just down that with .iso files.

(Feel free to be pedantic, I am not an expert (obviously) with this kind of stuff. I get some of it, and other parts seem a bit magic...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this page](http://web2.clarkson.edu/projects/itl/honeypot/ddtutorial.txt) has everything you need.

- instead of sdb make use of loopback device
- instead of actual card make use of virtual filesystem
- you are in the right track making use of dd to create a file for the virtual filesystem.
- you are in the right track using loopback device. The trick is mounting the loopback device in the offsets where the partitions are.

This is the article.

> A virtual filesystem is filesystem that exists in a file, which in
>   turn exists on a physical disk. There's a lot of great things you can
>   do with virtual file systems; the reason I was messing with them was
>   to configure a virtual machine on a linux host. Other uses include
>   encrypting filesystems without encrypting entire disks; Mac OS X's
>   File Vault encrypts users home directories this way. Maybe you went
>   ahead and made yourself one giant partition and then realized for one
>   reason or another that you want multiple partitions! Virtual
>   filesystems can help (to some extent) with that as well.
>
> So how do you make a virtual file system? Easy. The first thing you
>   need to do is make a file for the filesystem to live in. This is where
>   'dd' starts to come in. Consider, for example, the following command:
>
> dd if=/dev/zero of=~/myFileSystem.img bs=1024 count=1048576
>
> This command will read 1,048,576 blocks from /dev/zero and write them
>   to ~/myFileSystem.img; each block is 1024 bytes, resulting in a 1
>   gigabyte file containing all zeroes. The actual values that you use
>   for the blocksize (bs) and count aren't really important, the key is
>   to get your math right: bs * count = imageSize.
>
> So now you have your file; great. It's time to make a file system!
>   this part is even easier... we'll create an EXT2 filesystem, using the
>   following command:
>
> mke2fs myFileSystem.img
>
> You may notice a warning prompt, saying that myFileSystem.img is not a
>   block device, would you like to proceed? We'll get to that in just a
>   second, for now, go ahead and say yes. Everything should go smooth,
>   it'll look just as if you'd created a filesystem on an actual disk
>   drive. You now have a virtual file system! The only thing left to do
>   is mount your filesystem so you can access it...
>
> mkdir /mnt/virtual
>
> mount -o loop ~/myFileSystem.img /mnt/virtual
>
> Now any file you put into /mnt/virtual is actually being put directly
>   into myFileSystem.img! Wasn't that easy?
>
> Fantastic. Now that you know how to make a virtual filesytsem, why not
>   make a while virtual disk image? What's the difference you ask? A disk
>   image is going to have a partition table that defines some number of
>   partitions, and each partition contains its own filesystem; so a
>   virtual filesystem is essentially a "virtual partition" of a virtual
>   disk image; the virtual disk image contains multiple virtual
>   filesystems, and a virtual partition table that describes where the
>   bounds of each partition are.
>
> Creating a virtual disk image starts out the same; the first thing you
>   need is a big empty file, just you created above. This time, though,
>   instead of making a file system, we'll want to partition the file
>   using fdisk. To make things a little nicer though, we're going to
>   throw loopback devices into the mix. You should make sure you have
>   loopback device support enabled in your kernel (most distributions do
>   by default; but if you're a kernel compiling linux junky, you might
>   wanna check ). So we'll create a big file, and attach it to a loopback
>   device, as follows:
>
> dd if=/dev/zero of=~/myDisk.img bs=1024 count=1048576
>
> losetup /dev/loop0 ~/myDisk.img
>
> By attaching the disk image to the loopback device, we can use
>   /dev/loop0 the same way we would use ~/myDisk.img; the main difference
>   is that /dev/loop0 is a what's known as a "block device". You'd have
>   to ask someone with more experience than I've got what precisely this
>   gets you, but what I do know is that the filesystem utilities work
>   better with block devices than they do with the flat files. Plus, it's
>   fun.
>
> So good, we've got a big empty file attached to a loopback device
>   (/dev/loop0)... now it's time to create partitions in the disk image.
>   To do this, we'll run fdisk on our loopback device:
>
> fdisk /dev/loop0
>
> Lets create three partitions... if you're following this, you should
>   already be familiar with fdisk, so go ahead and create the following:
>         Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>
> /dev/loop0p1               1          17      136521   83  Linux
>
> /dev/loop0p2              18          80      506047+  82  Linux swap
>
> /dev/loop0p3              81         130      401625   83  Linux
>
> Once you've made your partitions, write your changes and quit fdisk.
>   What we'll need to do next is create filesystems on each partition.
>   Remember how easy that was back with Virtual Filesystems? Not quite so
>   much anymore...
>
> Not to panic though... the trouble is that "mkfs" can't "reach into"
>   our virtual disk image and make a filesystem just on individual
>   partition. Infact, if you try, you'll probably wind up wiping our your
>   virtual disk image and having to rerun fdisk . So what to do... what
>   to do?? Loopback devices to the rescue. What we'll do is attach a
>   loopback device to the myDisk.img file at the specific offsets where
>   each partition begins.
>
> It's helpful then to look at the partitions in terms of blocks.
>   Execute the following command:
>
> fdisk -ul /dev/loop0
>
> should look (hopefully exactly) like this:
>
> Disk /dev/loop0: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes
>
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 130 cylinders, total 2097152 sectors
>
> Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>
> ```
>   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> ```
>
> /dev/loop0p1              63      273104      136521   83  Linux
>
> /dev/loop0p2          273105     1285199      506047+  82  Linux swap
>
> /dev/loop0p3         1285200     2088449      401625   83  Linux
>
> These numbers are important for the math... we'll use the losetup
>   command like we did before, only this time we'll reach in specifically
>   to the start of each of the three partitions. losetup takes offsets as
>   the number of bytes to skip at the beginning of the file. The output
>   from fdisk -ul /dev/loop0 shows us that the first partition starts at
>   block 63, and that each block is 512 bytes. So partition 1 starts at
>   byte 32,256
>
> losetup -o 32256 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop0
>
> That command reaches 32,256 bytes into /dev/loop0 and mounts it at
>   /dev/loop1. Remember that since /dev/loop0 is attached the myDisk.img
>   file, this is the same as reaching 32,256 bytes into that file...
>   follow? Ok, good. Same logic for partitions 2 and 3:
>
> losetup -o 139829760 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop0
>
> losetup -o 658022400 /dev/loop3 /dev/loop0
>
> So now we have four loopback devices set up; /dev/loop0 is attached to
>   the myDisk.img file. /dev/loop1 is the first partition of the virtual
>   disk represented by /dev/loop0; /dev/loop2 is the 2_nd, and /dev/loop3
>   is the 3_rd.
>
> Now it's finally time to make those file systems! This is now just as
>   easy as making a regular filesystem, since that's all we're doing.
>   Remember, mkfs doesn't know the device isn't a physical device! We'll
>   make three kinds of file systems, an ext2 file system for partition 1,
>   a swap filesystem for partition 2, and an XFS fileystem for partition
>   3:
>
> mkfs /dev/loop1
>
> mkswap /dev/loop2
>
> mkfs.xfs /dev/loop3
>
> Since loop1, loop2, and loop3 are tied directly to loop0, and loop0 is
>   ~/myDisk.img, everything that we just did to loop1, loop2, and loop3
>   affected myDisk.img directly! We can now mount /dev/loop3, for
>   instance, on /mnt/virtual as an XFS file system, and use it as a
>   regular file system!
>
> So I hope you found that helpful... you can do some pretty neat things
>   with virtual file systems and virtual disk images; and loopback
>   devices make a world of difference for making things go smooth.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer to this problem is factually correct, but—as I write this *five years later*—there's a simpler approach that ought to work for most people. Manually juggling offsets and creating *multiple* loopback devices is, in general, no longer necessary. The 'secret weapon' for creating virtual filesystem images in most Linux distributions nowadays is the `-P` option to the [losetup command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/losetup.8.html):

```
-P, --partscan
              Force the kernel to scan the partition table on a newly created loop device.
```

You can basically think of `-P` as the "pretend this file is a *disk*" option. An example should make this clear. This command creates a 4GB image file filled with zeroes:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=./sdcard.img bs=1024 count=4194304
4194304+0 records in
4194304+0 records out
4294967296 bytes (4.3 GB, 4.0 GiB) copied, 39.7914 s, 108 MB/s
```

The following command maps the first available loopback device to this file, and does so in a way that the kernel interprets the bytes at the beginning as a *partition table*:

```
$ sudo losetup -fP ./sdcard.img

$ losetup --list
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /home/evadeflow/Desktop/sdcard.img
```

It may seem like a small thing, but passing `-P` means that you can now use tools like `fdisk` to partition the 'disk' mapped via `/dev/loop0`. Here, I create a 128 MB partition at the beginning, and a second partition to house all the remaining space:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/loop0
GNU Fdisk 1.3.0a
Copyright (C) 1998 - 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
Using /dev/loop0
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/loop0: 4 GB, 4293596160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   e   extended
   p   primary partition (1-4)
p
First cylinder  (default 0cyl):
Last cylinder or +size or +sizeMB or +sizeKB  (default 521cyl): +128M
Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   e   extended
   p   primary partition (1-4)
p
First cylinder  (default 15cyl):
Last cylinder or +size or +sizeMB or +sizeKB  (default 521cyl):
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/loop0: 4 GB, 4293596160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/loop0p1               1          16      128488   83  Linux
Warning: Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/loop0p2              16         522     4064445   83  Linux
Command (m for help): w
Information: Don't forget to update /etc/fstab, if necessary.


Writing all changes to /dev/loop0.
```

Note that Linux created new loopback devices on your behalf for each of the two partitions: `/dev/loop0p1` and `/dev/loop0p2`. You can see their relationship with `/dev/loop` by running `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk /dev/loop0
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0       7:0    0     4G  0 loop
├─loop0p1 259:2    0 122.1M  0 loop
└─loop0p2 259:3    0   3.9G  0 loop
```

To populate these partitions, you can create filesystems using the loopback devices `/dev/loop0p1` and `/dev/loop0p2`, then simply *mount* them, and copy files into the mount points. The process looks sorta like this:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p1
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p2
$ mkdir part1-stuff part2-stuff
$ sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 ./part1-stuff
$ sudo mount /dev/loop0p2 ./part2-stuff
$ cp /stuff-source/part1/* ./part1-stuff
$ cp /stuff-source/part2/* ./part2-stuff
$ sudo umount ./part1-stuff
$ sudo umount ./part2-stuff
```

Once the partitions look the way you want them to, simply 'detach' `/dev/loop0` from the file using:

```
$ sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Note that this also detaches the `/dev/loop0p1` and `/dev/loop0p2` devices that Linux created for you.

So, all in all the accepted answer remains 100% correct, and provides valuable insight into what's going on under the covers. But if your distribution's `losetup` supports the `-P` option, you can just use standard partitioning tools and let Linux handle creation (and *deletion*) of the loop 'sub-device' for each partition.

Comment: The accepted answer should be this one!